# Primefaces: EventBusFactory.getDefault() devuelve null

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, atmosphere

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Primefaces que utiliza el modelo pub/sub facilitado por este framework.

Pila tecnológica:

- tomcat 8
- java 8
- primefaces 6
- atmosphere-runtime 2.4.7

En el fichero ***web.xml*** defino el servlet para Push:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Cuando intento obtener una instancia de `Eventbus` para lanzar una notificación, `EventBusFactory` me retorna `null`:

```
EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
eventBus.publish(notificacion.getRuta(), notificacion);
```

He indagado por los foros de primefaces donde indican que el problema debería solventarse introduciendo el parámetro `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` de ***web.xml***, sin embargo no es mi caso.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570117/nullpointerexception-when-using-primepush-eventbus-primefaces-6-0

Comment: He probado pero sigue devolviendo null.

Answer (score 1):

sólo hay que poner el código siguiente para un constructor por defecto

```
public ChatView() {eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus(); }
```

Se trabajará para cualquier versión

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```